# How to compute the L^2-distance of a given function to the set of Gaussian functions

Tags: probability, integration

I am faced with the following question: given a probability density function $f$ over $\mathbb{R}$ with $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)x^2dx=\sigma^2$ given, I am trying to find the "nearest" Gaussian to $\sqrt{f}$ in $L^2$, i.e. compute
$$\inf_{a\in \mathbb{R}, b > 0}\|\sqrt{f}-G_{a,b}\|_2^2$$
where $G_{a,b}(x)=a\exp(-bx^2)$ and the $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the classical $L^2$-norm over $\mathbb{R}.$

If one replaces the $L^2$-distance by the relative entropy $H(f|G_{a,b})$, it is easy to check that the infimum is a minimum given by the centered gaussian with variance $\sigma^2.$ For the $L^2$-distance, it seems more involved......

Comment: I am a little confused. Could you please clarify a couple of points? 1) You call $f$ a "distribution function" but then you use it in the definition of variance and KL divergence as if it were a probability density function. 2) When you say "the nearest Gaussian", do you mean a normalized Gaussian pdf or simply a Gaussian function? In other words, can $a$ and $b$ be anything or is $a=\sqrt{b/\pi}$? 3) You used KL to find a measure of distance between $f$ and $G_{a,b}$ but then you ask to find the $L^2$ distance between $\sqrt{f}$ and $G_{a,b}$. Is that right or is the square root a typo?

Comment: You are right. Terminology may be a little confusing. The function $f$ is a probability density function. We consider here any kind of (centered) Gaussian, there is no restriction on $a,b$ except $b >0$. Finally, the KL is for $f$ but the $L^2$-distance is for $\sqrt{f}$ (since $\sqrt{f}$ belongs to $L^2$)  -- if you wish, in the $L^2$ distance, you can also take the square root of the Gaussian since  the square root of a Gaussian is still a Gaussian. Thanks for the comments. I will edit some changes.